# Getting Shared Preferences with specific name

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store multiple variables from various EditText and Textview Boxes in a shared Preference which I has a specific name (so no default shared Preferences possible). Saving from Activity C and later retrieving works fine. However, if I save them in the Fragment of Activity D and try to retrieve it later, I get a blank field. Even the default value isn't shown. It must have something to do with the fragment, but I couldn't find the right syntax to get it to work. This answer ([Shared Preferences in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366626/shared-preferences-in-fragment) among others) couldn't help me (since it is using default shared Preferences).

Here is part of the on create method of Activity C where the shared preferences are committed

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_produktspezifikation);

        //region BUTTON DEKLARATION
        Button neuesWST = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Neu_WST);
        neuesWST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(C_Produktspezifikation.this,WST_bearbeiten.class));
            }
        });

        Button Weiter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Produktspezifikation_weiter);
        Weiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //region DATEN SPEICHERN
                //Variablen definieren, um die Daten aus den Feldern auszulesen
                TextView WstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_WST);
                TextView Schnittweg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Schnittweg_Eintrag);
                EditText Stueckzahl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Stuekzahl_Eintrag);
                EditText Losgroesse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Losgroesse_Eintrag);

                //Shared Preferences definieren
                SharedPreferences sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("Datenspeicher", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();

                //Daten in benannter SharedPreference speichern
                editor.putString("wstname", WstName.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("schnittweg", Schnittweg.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("stueckzahl", Stueckzahl.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("losgroesse", Losgroesse.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                //endregion

                startActivity(new Intent(C_Produktspezifikation.this,D_Maschine.class));

            }
        });
```

Except of fragment of Activity D (The other is identical) where more preferences are safed:

```
public class Maschine_v1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maschine_variante_1, container, false);

        //Variablen definieren, um die Daten aus den Feldern auszulesen
        TextView maschinenname_v1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_m_v1_Maschine);
        TextView anschaffungswert_v1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_m_v1_Anschaffungswert_Eintrag);
        TextView raumbedarf_v1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_m_v1_Raumbedarf_Eintrag);
        TextView el_Anschlusswert_v1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_m_v1_el_Anschlusswert_Eintrag);

        //Shared Preferences definieren
        SharedPreferences sharedpref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Datenspeicher", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();

        //Daten in benannter SharedPreference speichern
        editor.putString("maschinenname_v1", maschinenname_v1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("anschaffungswert_v1", anschaffungswert_v1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("raumbedarf_v1", raumbedarf_v1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("el_anschlusswert_v1", el_Anschlusswert_v1.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
```

And a Fragment of Activity E where the shared Preferences from Activity D are supposed to be retrieved and aren't shown:
anschaffungswert_v1 comes from activity D (or rahter it's fragment) and doesn't work.

Schnittweg comes from activity C and works.

```
public class Werkzeug_v1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_werkzeug_variante_1, container, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_v1_Werkzeug_Abnutzung_Eintrag);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_v1_Werkzeug_Schnittweg_Eintrag);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Datenspeicher", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String test = sharedPref.getString("anschaffungswert_v1","N/A");
        String test2 = sharedPref.getString("schnittweg", "");
        tv.setText(test);
        tv2.setText(test2);
```

Here is the `Datenspeicher.xml` (my shared Preferences file) after saving in Activity D:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="anschaffungswert_v1"></string>
    <string name="maschinenname_v1"></string>
    <string name="schnittweg">1200</string>
    <string name="el_anschlusswert_v1"></string>
    <string name="losgroesse"></string>
    <string name="wstname">WerkstÃ¼ck 1</string>
    <string name="stueckzahl">33</string>
    <string name="raumbedarf_v1"></string>
</map>
```

Comment: sorry for the codespam. I was afraid to miss an important part that I wasn't aware of. And I totally overlooked, that the regions were not collapsed.

Comment: Try to check sharedPreference file just after saving in fragment of Activity D. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392716/6168272

Comment: The entries are empty, as I expected (I edited my question and provided the xml file). I still don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

Try using tiny DB... Just add the tinyDB.java to your project...  https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo?files=1

Comment: It uses gson to serialize objects and wtf, it even saves png as base64, performance is terrible.